# skip/ignore parent's (.wrapper) background settings

Tags: html, css

[image]

First of all I'd like to say that I am new to all this. So, here is my situation.

I have set a background image for my entire body.
I have a div .wrapper that I include in all my pages. It's main purpose is to keep my content centered and organized. It's background color is set to grey. 
Inside the div .wrapper there is another div .example.

I want this particular div .example to take the background-image of the body and not the color of the .wrapper, but still keep the rest of the .wrapper's properties. Is it possible? I tried no to set the background-image of the .example the same as the body's because I think it shows like a "foreign" object...

```
<html>
...
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="example">
        <img src="example.png">
    </div>
</div> <!-- Wrapper -->
</body>
</html>

body { 
    background: #ffffff url("bg.jpg") repeat;
    background-size: 4%;
    background-position: center;
} 

.wrapper {  
    width: 80vw;
    margin: auto;  
    padding: 0px 0px;
    background: #e9eaed; 
    display: block; 
}  

.example {
    width: 100%;
/*  background-color: #f6c5b6;*/

}

.example img {
    width:40%;
    margin: 40px auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: er... not sure what you are trying to get at. but literally is not possible, just set the background image of your div.example and use `background-position: xpx ypx;` to match it. I think that would be the best way to do this

Comment: I 've got a background image with vertical blue and red stripes. The purpose of it, is to appear on both sides of screen (outside wrapper). I found out that what suits me best (visually) is to set it at 4% and center. If I just put the same background for my .example div, the two backgrounds do not match. I want them to appear as one big background, not like having one big with a smaller one into it. 
I get the wanted output if I skip the wrapper for this page and just set a new class with the image size I like. But I am wondering if I could somehow declare to skip the wrapper's background img

Comment: I add A sample image to the question, please let me know if that is what you want to achieve.

Comment: You are actually breaking the wrapper and insert another div in between. My problem is that my background image is small and I repeat it in x and y many times, so cant cover. 
Since I have a wrapper in my main page that is i.e. 800px wide, I want all divs inside it to have the same width (unless specifically changed). Is it possible to use the class wrapper but without one of its properties (width, margin, padding, but not the same background) ? 
From your answer my guess is that there is no way to do that directly...

Comment: yeah... I don't know any other way, you can try background-clip or svg mask. but that is complicated and browser support is ">ie8" background-repeat is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Only way to achieve this is to build your div around it.

```css
.body {
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/g/40/40');
    width: 500px; height:700px; background-repeat:repeat;
}
.wrapper {
    width:300px; height:50px; background:grey; margin:0 auto;    
}
.mask {
    width: 300px; height:100px; margin:0 auto; 
}
.left {
    width: 50px; height:100px; float:left; background:red;
}
.right {
    width: 50px; height:100px; float:right; background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class='body'>
    <div class="wrapper">
        box 1
    </div>
    <div class="mask">
        <div class="left">
            box 2
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            box 3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
            box 4
    </div>
    
</div>
```